# Sed to delete lines containg n charcters

Tags: sed

I have many lines in a file which only contain '--' on each line which i want to rmeove. But there are many other lines in the file that contain 'SOMETEXT--SOMETEXT'.

sed -i "/--/d" will remove all instances of '--' but I only want to remove all lines that contain only '--'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `^` and `$` to indicate beginning and end of line
`sed -i '/^--$/d'`

Answer (score 0):

A line containing only `--` would match the regex `^--$`

If you want to include lines with leading/trailing whitespaces, it could be extended to

```
^\s*--\s*$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i '/^--$/' file
```

The `^` and `$` chars "anchor" the search to the beginning and end of the line, respectively.

OR if there can be spaces at the front or back AND assuming an modernish `sed`

```
sed -i '/^[[:space:]]*--[[:space:]]*$/' file
```

where `[:space:]` will find space chars and tabs.

ELSE a total retro `sed` should handle

```
sed  '/^[ ]*--[ ]*$/' file > newFile && mv newFile file
```

and if there could be tabs, then just include a tab char along with the space char, i.e.\

```
[<Space><TAB>]
```

but not spelled, out, just typing a space char and a tab char will do it.

IHTH